# Term.IsAvailableForTagging

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, managed-metadata, term

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.term.isavailablefortagging(v=office.14).aspx)

Gets or sets the flag indicating whether a Term object can be used to tag in the tagging UI, but does not affect its visibility.

I am just confused and want to know what is tagging UI?

Can anybody explain little bit more the above definition?

Comment: I'm assuming the UI they are talking about is the picker on a managed metadata field.

Answer (score 0):

By *tagging UI* [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.term.isavailablefortagging(v=office.14).aspx) refers to [TaxonomyWebTaggingControl ASP.NET web control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomywebtaggingcontrol%28v=office.14%29.aspx) that *represents a generic Web control for picking managed metadata terms*.

According to [Using SharePoint TaxonomyWebTaggingControl control: Access and manipulate from client side](http://blog.vgrem.com/2013/01/23/using-sharepoint-taxonomywebtaggingcontrol-control-access-and-manipulate-from-client-side/), [TaxonomyWebTaggingControl ASP.NET web control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomywebtaggingcontrol%28v=office.14%29.aspx) is a server side wrapper for `Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.ScriptForWebTaggingUI` JavaScript control from SharePoint client library (`ScriptForWebTaggingUI.js`).

The list of application pages that leverages `Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.ScriptForWebTaggingUI` contol:

- `/_layouts/TaxonomyTreePicker.aspx`
- `/_layouts/TermStoreManager.aspx`
- `/_layouts/WebTaggingDialog.aspx`